# How to preserve unsized data created in a closure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create unsized data in a callback, and store the reference in a vector. Is this possible in any way?

```
fn main() {

    let mut results = vec![];

    let mut callback = |val: &str| results.push(val.clone());
    //  ERROR:                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `val` escapes the closure body here

    for s in ["a","b","c"] {
        callback(s);
    };
}
```

---

Okay, so in working this I found a solution, but I have questions about it.

```
use std::clone::Clone;

pub fn main() {

    let mut results = vec![];

    let mut callback = |val: &str| results.push(Clone::clone(&val.to_owned()));

    for s in ["a","b","c"] {
        callback(s);
    };
}
```

Why does this work but neither `val.clone()` or `&(val.clone())` work?

Why doesn't the complier complain about not knowing the size of `results` beforehand?

Does this work for any unsized type?

If I call `callback(s)` twice it works as expected. Why doesn't `to_owned()` consume the resource?

Is there anything else important here that I (or someone else at my level who might be reading this) am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into bunch misconceptions.

1. When you call `clone` on `&str`, you get another `&str`. It is useless, as long as any reference implements `Copy`.
2. You're trying to insert reference to `str` with non-`static` lifetime into a vector with static lifetime. Ask yourself: what would happen, if the object behind the reference will die before this vector? You'll get a vector of dangling references => undefined behavior.

This code will work:

```
fn main() {

    let mut results = vec![]; // results has type `Vec<&'static str>`

    let mut callback = |val: &'static str| results.push(val);
    for s in ["a","b","c"] {
        callback(s);
    };
}
```

3. You don't need to `use std::clone::Clone` as long as it's already in `std::prelude` and accessible in every scope.
4. When you call `to_owned` on `&str`, you actually create a `String` which  has `'static` lifetime. So you can insert any `String` into a `Vec`. But it is not a reference to the original `str` anymore. Also you don't need to call `clone` here.

So this will work too:

```
pub fn main() {

    let mut results = vec![]; // results has type `Vec<String>`

    let mut callback = |val: &str| results.push(val.to_owned());

    for s in ["a","b","c"] {
        callback(s);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. `'static' is very useful. Is it possible to set the lifetime of the string to the same lifetime of the vector so the data isn't allocated for the entire duration of the program?

Comment: @v4gil Because the `Vec` takes ownership of the string, the strings lifetime will be the same as the `Vec`s,unless they are moved out of it.